# Check if a letter is in a bidimensional list

Tags: python, list, integer, indices

I have created a list containing the abecedary with a related words in a bidimensional list.
but when i try to to find a word contained in the list and print the related words, it throws me:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

Here is my code:

```
import parallel
import time
import string

abc=[['a','EB'], ['b','F8']]

print ("Write something: ")
text = raw_input()
lent=len(text)
print (lent)
p=parallel.Parallel()
text1=list(text)

for x in text1:
print (x)
    i=0
for i in abc:
    if x in abc[0][i]:
           print(abc[0][i])
       p.setData(int('0x'+abc[0][i],16))

 time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> abc = [['a','EB'],['b','F8']]
>>> for i in abc:
...    print i
...
['a', 'EB']
['b', 'F8']
```

So you probably need this:

```
for i in abc:
    if x == i[0]:
           print(i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The type error is here

```
 if x in abc[0][i]:
```

`i` is going to be a list, the first pass `i` will be `['a','EB']`, and the second pass `i` will be `['b','F8']`

It does not make sense to index something with another list, you probably thought `i` was the index, but in python the for loop will loop through values instead.